# What packages and functions to use to create this diagram?

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science

I have a Data Science related project. I need to visualize my variables. I can do it using bar charts and scatterplots, but I have been asked to make a diagram like this. The problem is, I don't even know where to begin or what packages to use. If someone can guide me, It will be great. I must use Python. 
[The diagram I need to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKMh7.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try one of the Python Graphwiz adaptations:

- https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz
- http://pygraphviz.github.io/